# node: command not found - in wsl bash

Tags: linux, windows, docker, wsl-2

I install docker on my windows 10. after that I get a message that I need to download and install `wsl2`.

Now, when I run `bash` command I get wsl `bash`.

When I try to run `node` I get an error (**node.exe is installed in my windows10**):

```
DESKTOP-BVRDS:/tmp/docker-desktop-root/mnt/host/c/Users/myuser# node
bash: node: command not found
```

when I run `echo $PATH` I get output of:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

and not the windows path's. (where the node and other software installed).

How to solve this error? maybe change the default bash? to git bash? (which I don't know how)

Answer (score 0):

In Cmder, open settings: `Win` + `Alt` + `P`

1. Under Startup > Tasks, add a task called {bash} with the following settings:

   Task parameters (set icon):

```
      For Cmder icon:  /icon "%CMDER_ROOT%\cmder.exe"
```

```
      For Git icon: /icon "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\etc\git.ico"
```

Commands (open Git's bash shell):

```
      "C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" -l -new_console:d:%USERPROFILE%
```

2. Under Startup, set startup options to `Specified name task --> {bash}`

Please check below a couple of articles and should solve an issue.

> https://gist.github.com/nickautomatic/02ccb76292f7f8d9767e
>   https://gingter.org/2016/11/16/running-windows-10-ubuntu-bash-in-cmder/

Comment: Its works when I open new tab in cmder. but as default I open cmd tab, and then I run `bash` command in a file script like `npm run deploy` which run `bash deploy.sh`. and then the wsl run instead of git bash. so this is the problem.

Comment: I have posted another answer, please have a look once

Answer (score 0):

Please try below:

1. Open a regular command prompt (`win+r` then `cmd`)
2. Right-click the title bar and select `Properties`
3. Deselect "Use legacy console (requires restart)"

Now it should work either by launching the standalone app, or typing `bash` into a regular `cmd` window after restarting Command Prompt.

Comment: I did as you say, but now when I run bash I get error: `Unsupported console settings. In order to use this feature, the legacy console must be disabled.`

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to `deselct` the legacy console and then restart the computer

Comment: Can you please check this article once, https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/bash-does-not-start-unsupported-console-settings-windows-10/
I am assuming something is wrong the way you done it

Comment: And if no success, can you try `lxrun /uninstall /full` and then `lxrun /install` again

Comment: I see that still lagacy is checked, so I unchecked it again and restart.  now it unchecked and docker say nothing. but when I run `bash` nothing happens. the process say nothing and exit.